# Adding a UIActivityIndicatorView to a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

How is a UIActivityIndicatorView added to a UITableViewController?

I have tried adding it in Interface Builder and when I drag and drop it onto the view, it just disappears.

I need to show the activityIndicator while the table loads in its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add UIActivityIndicatorView to your tables in the Interface Builder (IB), but a recommended way would be:

- User IB to create and customize a UITableViewCell. Put a UIActivityIndicatorView inside this cell.
- Programmatically load your table cells with the customized UITableViewCell nib file.
- Programmatically hook up IBOutlets of such UIActivityIndicatorView.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a tableview (not a tableview controller) inside another view you can place the activity indicator on top of it. To clarify:
- Plain xib file with a Files Owner and a First Responder
- Add a View (not a view controller)
- Add a TableView into the View
- Add an Activity Indicator into the View

For some reason, the various view controller objects don't like you adding things to them and the tableview object doesn't like you adding things to it. I'm sure that the docs make this really clear somewhere.